# Unable to run script within Visual Studio setup package

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer

I have created a setup within Visual Studio, which require to run some .vbs script while installer package getting install.

Have added script in "custom Actions" but getting error while setup running.

"There is a problem with this Windows Installer Package. A script required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor."

[image]

have tried to adding from "custom actions">install

[image]

Comment: I get this error also. Tried with .js file that runs successfully outside the installer..

Comment: thanks for the input
i was able to bypass the issue, using batch script via command line

Comment: Did you manage to run your script without the installer eventually copy it (or e.g. the cmd app) to the target installation folder? If so, will be happy for your solution:)

Comment: yes copied the cmd.exe to target directory and the added in arguments to run from there